# PHP : Add reply-to text to the mail when someone replies to mail

Tags: php, email

I am sending mail to customer with reply to email-id , when customer click reply to , a predefined text should be added to contain body and customer will type contain after that.
How this can be done ?

Comment: You can't. That is up to the email software the client uses. You cannot control that.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the headers to be able to pass the [sender email](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```